# Can I parameterize the data source on a wpf hierarchical data template?

Tags: wpf, treeview, binding, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a hierarchical data structure with two similar sub-trees:

```
Iteration:
   string  Name
   string  Image
   ObservableCollection<Iteration>  SubIterations
   ObservableCollection<Iteration>  BacklogIterations
```

I want to present two slightly different views of the tree, using two tree views.

- Tree1: Display the SubIterations
- Tree2: Display the BacklogIterations

The elements should be displayed the same, but the child items need to be picked up using a different property.

i.e. I want to parameterize the ItemsSource in the HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="IterationItem"
  ItemsSource="{Binding SubIterations}"
  >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Width="32" Height="32" 
       Margin="3,0" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootSprintIteration}">
</TreeView>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootBacklogIteration}">
</TreeView>
```

How can I get the HierarchicalDataTemplate in the second tree to use a different ItemsSource? 
I do not want to duplicate the whole HierarchicalDataTemplate definition just to change the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Viauslization of the data in a DataTemplate and create two HierarchicalDataTemplates where you set the ItemTemplate to the created DataTemplate. There exist no reason why you shouoldnt create two HierarchicalDataTemplates. They offer you exactly the parametrization you wish and allow you to use the same ItemTemplate for both